# how to display the data in the Table view of IOS while using RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, restkit

I'm developing an app in IOS using **RestKit**. Data is retrieved successfully but i'm not able to display it in the Table view (i.e. rows are empty). when i scroll the table, rows are displayed correctly (i.e. data is there !!).

You will get the better idea from the code.(for just the simplicity, i provided the rough outline of the code, let me know if more code is needed.)

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad_inside!!");
    RKRequest* request = [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/urlstring" delegate:self];
    [request send];
    NSLog(@"request is sent");
    [super viewDidLoad];
} 

- (void)requestDidStartLoad:(RKRequest *)request {
       NSLog(@"request did start Load");
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
         NSLog(@"request didLoadResponse");
......
  //rest of the code Logic
...... 

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"table_inside!!");
}
```

**code executes successfully but Table's rows are empty.!!**

**Output:**

viewDidLoad_inside!!

request did start Load

request is sent

table_inside

request didLoadResponse

So the problem is, methods are not executing in proper order. why this is happening?. How to resolve it. is there any better approche to do so. I'm new to IOS so couldn't figured it out.

**I tried Peter Kelly's answer and that works fine. But the tableView method must not be executed until the records are retrieved successfully. How to change the execution sequence.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you reloaded your tableView after you have all the data?

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for such a quick answer. Your solution works !!. But if the size of the data is too large then the response of the restKit takes long time. Until the data retrieved, rows remains empty that gives a ugly look. Is there any alternative by which table will not be displayed until the whole data is retrieved successfully. Thanx again. :-)

Comment: no problem. (You can upvote and accept the answer if you like it...). I would probably ask another question with your new problem - better than trying to discuss it in the comments I'd say. You can show a spinner control until the data is loaded.